Dead End recognizion in room generation, unity
So I've got this room generation with different rooms connected by corridors.
Now I want the player to spawn at one of the dead ends of the rooms. To check for dead ends, I just scan each direction for corridors and store the count on a variable. If this variable is equal to 1, the room should be a dead end. The problem is, that not every dead ends are recognized and sometimes, even normal rooms are listed as dead ends.
 Here is the picture of an example generation. The pink center is the dead end recognized. The green dots are room centers and the orange ones are the corridors checked around the centers. Still there are green dead ends. This is the important code, basically just a loop through all rooms and corridor positions where the positions are kept in a hashset
        int roomCorridorCount = 0;
    HashSet<Vector2Int> corridors = ConnectRooms(roomCenters);
    HashSet<Vector2Int> deadEnds = new HashSet<Vector2Int>();
    HashSet<Vector2Int> nearRoomCenter = new HashSet<Vector2Int>();
    HashSet<Vector2Int> oneCorridorRooms = new HashSet<Vector2Int>();
    foreach (var room in newRoomCenters)
    {
        foreach (var corridor in corridors)
        {
            if(new Vector2Int(room.x + 1, room.y) == corridor)
            {
                roomCorridorCount++;
                nearRoomCenter.Add(new Vector2Int(room.x + 1, room.y));
            }   
            if (new Vector2Int(room.x - 1, room.y) == corridor)
            {
                roomCorridorCount++;
                nearRoomCenter.Add(new Vector2Int(room.x - 1, room.y));
            }
            if(new Vector2Int(room.x, room.y + 1) == corridor)
            {
                roomCorridorCount++;
                nearRoomCenter.Add(new Vector2Int(room.x, room.y + 1));
            }
            if(new Vector2Int(room.x, room.y - 1) == corridor)
            {
                roomCorridorCount++;
                nearRoomCenter.Add(new Vector2Int(room.x, room.y - 1));
            }           
        }
        if (roomCorridorCount == 1)
        {
            deadEnds.Add(room);
            oneCorridorRooms.Add(room);
        }
    }
    tilemapVisualizer.PaintTiles(corridors, floorMap, white);
    tilemapVisualizer.PaintTiles(newRoomCenters, floorMap, green);
    tilemapVisualizer.PaintTiles(nearRoomCenter, floorMap, orange);
    tilemapVisualizer.PaintTiles(oneCorridorRooms, floorMap, pink);
    floor.UnionWith(corridors);
    var playerSpawnRoom = deadEnds.ElementAt(Random.Range(0, deadEnds.Count));
    Debug.Log(deadEnds.Count);


what about that one right under the pink one ... that's not really a dead end even though there is only one orange field :D also check the bottom ones .. there is two ways passing the same room but the lower one isn't even considered ... what I mean is I suppose in general you need a better way of determining your exits

Because you never reset the roomCorridorCount throughout.

and I guess @shingo just spotted the main issue ^^

It was the missing reset of the variable uff. To @derHugo, I just want to have two rooms out of all the dead ends so not getting every room is totally fine

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
